# Trouble with floating point equivalence (I think)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have read that `==` has trouble with floating points. eg:

## good

```
74.2+53.2
[1] 127.4
74.2+53.2==127.4
[1] TRUE
```

## bad

```
74.2+153.2
[1] 227.4
74.2+153.2==227.4
[1] FALSE
```

## isTRUE and all.equal

```
isTRUE(all.equal(74.2+153.2, 227.4))
[1] TRUE
```

Using `dplyr` to `group_by` a variable, then `summarise` one variable as `sum` and the `max` of another, then look for equivalency.

## First a working example:  74.2+53.2=127.4

```
library(dplyr)
df<-tibble(group=c(  1,     2,     2,   3),
           B=    c(1.0,  74.2,  53.2, 1.0),
           C=    c(  2, 127.4, 127.4, 1.0))
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(sumB = sum(B),
            maxC = max(C)) %>% 
  mutate(equal = case_when(sumB== maxC ~ "yes"))
```

> ```
>   group  sumB  maxC equal
>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
> 1     1    1     2  NA   
> 2     2  127.  127. yes  
> 3     3    1     1  yes
> ```

## Now slightly larger numbers: 74.2+153.2=227.4

```
df<-tibble(group=c(1,2,2,3),
           B=c(1.0,74.2,153.2,1.0),
           C=c(2,227.4,227.4,1.0))

df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(sumB = sum(B),
            maxC = max(C)) %>% 
  mutate(equal = case_when(sumB== maxC ~ "yes"))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 4
>   group  sumB  maxC equal
>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
> 1     1    1     2  NA   
> 2     2  227.  227. NA   
> 3     3    1     1  yes
> ```

Direct math

```
74.2+153.2==227.4
```

> ```
> [1] FALSE
> ```

Now wrapped in `isTRUE()` and `all.equal()`

```
isTRUE(all.equal(74.2+153.2, 227.4))
```

> [1] TRUE

## Now a modified `case_when()`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(sumB = sum(B),
            maxC = max(C)) %>% 
  mutate(equal = case_when(isTRUE(all.equal(sumB, maxC)) ~ "yes"))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 4
>   group  sumB  maxC equal
>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
> 1     1    1     2  NA   
> 2     2  227.  227. NA   
> 3     3    1     1  NA
> ```

No, this is not the expected result. What is the correct way to solve this?

Comment: related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal

Comment: Thank you @akrun, the solution appears to be using the `near()` function.  `mutate(equal = case_when(near(sumB, maxC) ~ "yes"))`

Comment: I rolled back your edit. Please do not add solutions into questions.

Comment: To reiterate, `isTRUE(all.equal())` doesn't work inside a `case_when()`, use `dplyr::near()` instead. ps. `near()` has a nice `tol = ` argument that allows for a wide range of tolerance.